# Soft Limits for Sharepoint2010 document libraries, page libraries and lists

Tags: document-library, list

Our client plans to migrate from the existing Content Management System(non-Sharepoint) to Sharepoint2010. We need to specify soft limits for document library, page library and list to the client from a migration perspective(even i didn't understand what this is about :P)but my Team Lead told me this. I have been searching on soft limits for the above specified things but I have so far got very limited information. Can anyone provide more information from a migration perspective???Pointers to any whitepapers regarding the same would also be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information on TechNet here:

[SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management: Software boundaries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Lars, but i have gone through this but as i mentioned my client is migrating from a java-based CMS and i don't know what he meant by soft limits from a migration perspective :(..U have any idea???

Comment: Well, from a migration perspective you must simply migrate the content to SP2010 in such a way that you do not violate the SP2010 boundaries and limits. How do you plan to migrate - can you purchase a tool for the job or are you going to develop your own tool/script?

Comment: I think we would be developing our own script to migrate

Comment: Ok, I also doubt that there is a tool out there for the job. At least I have never heard of any migration tools from any java based systems to SharePoint!